# How does Shopify manage domains?

Tags: php, node.js, nginx, dns, shopify

I cant find any information about the technology Shopify uses to manage domains. I am developing a website builder similar to wix / shopify and this is the part that is stumping me.

My website uses node.js as backend, nginx as server.

Thanks.

Comment: You should study DNS. Once you master that, this question is answered for you. It is a broad subject, with many nuances. Enjoy!

Comment: I wanna know as well.  there is some lib for that?

Answer (score 0):

Shopify handles DNS inside their admin panel, merchant who use shopify can buy and park domain there right away, to detouch the domain management from Shopify in our specific flow we use Cloudflare it unlocks much more options to configure and manage more granularly.